# How to get a percentage from two different columns in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, subquery, percentage

My table is in postgre and I have this table1 in my database:

```
category  status   value
type a     open      4
type a     close     5
type b     open      3
type b     close     5
type c     open      2
type c     close     4
```

and I want to calculate the percentage of `open status` at each category.
The formula is:
`% type x (open) = (open / open + close) * 100`

with the query, I expect to get:

```
category    percentage
type a       44,44%
type b       60%
type c       50%
```

How can I get the desired result with query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can achieve this using a group by or window functions. What have you already tried? Do you get any errors or wrong output? You would learn more from trying and getting feedback from your attempt than just getting the answer.

Comment: Btw, wouldn't type b be `3 open / 8 total = 37,5%` and type c be `2 open / 6 total = 33,33%`?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a window that partitions your data on category as follows:

```
window w as ( partition by category )
```

Then you can aggregate over that window to get the number of open per category using the defined window:

```
sum(value) filter (where status = 'open') over w
```

In the same way you get the total per category using the defined window, the `nullif` is there to avoid division by 0:

```
nullif(sum(value) over w, 0)
```

To put it all together:

```
select distinct on (category)
      category,
      100 * sum(value) filter (where status = 'open') over w / nullif(sum(value) over w, 0) as percentage
from your_table
window w as ( partition by category );
```

As we are using window functions and not a grouping, we need to remove duplicates by adding the `distinct on (category)`

Answer (score 1):

I think aggregates would be most efficient:

```
SELECT category,
       100.0 *  -- use a decimal point to force floating point arithmetic
       sum(value) FILTER (WHERE status = 'open') /
       nullif(sum(value), 0) AS percentage  -- avoid division by zero
FROM your_table
GROUP BY category;
```